# What are CS:GO item float values, and do I calculate them?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

While searching on here for Minecraft related questions to answer, I've seen these questions about *item float values*.

I'm new to CS:GO, haven't heard of this many times before, but I've heard that it's possible to calculate it, which is something I don't know how to do.

So in a nutshell: What exactly are floating values, and how do I calculate them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1. What are float values?**

Float values are the precise wear value of a skin. This value is a value between 0 and 1, where 0 is the least wear. The float values are mostly used in trading and trade-ups, and for most people the exterior quality is enough to know.

This is what the exterior on the skin is based on.

```
0 - 0.07       Factory New
0.07 - 0.15    Minimal Wear
0.15 - 0.38    Field-Tested
0.38 - 0.45    Well-Worn
0.45 - 1       Battle-Scarred
```

Note that not all skins have the full range of possible values. A [AWP | Asiimov](https://csgostash.com/skin/274/AWP-Asiimov) for instance, can only have values between 0.18 and 1, making `Factory New`and `Minimal Wear`impossible.

**2. How can I calculate float values?**

You can not calculate a skins float value, but it is possible to find. There are several services that can tell you your exact float values. Examples are [CSGO Exchange](http://csgo.exchange) and [Steam Analyst](http://steamanalyst.com/).

In a trade-up contract on the other hand, you can calculate the float value of the item you will receive.

This is important if you're trying to "craft" a weapon. If the item you want has a full float value range (0-1) the formula is simple, its simply the average float value of all the low tier skin.

```
Wear on received item = Sum(All 10 trade up skins) / 10
```

If your trying to craft a weapon that does not have the full float value field, the formula is somewhat more complicated.

```
Wear on receiveed item = (MAX_FLOAT - MIN_FLOAT) * (Sum(All 10 trade up skins) / 10) + MIN_FLOAT
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Jorgen, It's highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out the specific float value of an asset, you can use a tool like the [CSGOFloat Checker](https://csgofloat.com/checker) in combination with the inspect link of the asset. If you want to know the possible float range of a skin, you can use [CSGOStash](https://csgostash.com) or [CSGOSKINS.GG](https://csgoskins.gg).